# Node Express Mongo API return empty result set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, rest, express

I'm going to develop API using Node Express & Mongo.I have manually entered data to mongo db like below and when i try to get data from the db it shows me empty in postman.Here i have paste my project code for easy to figure out.

In the controller returned empty results.

[image]

my project structure looks like this

### [image] 
db.config.json

```
module.exports = {
//url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/TestDb"
url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/Users"
 };
```

### server.js

```
    const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to Shopping List." });
});

require("./app/routes/user.routes")(app);
// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});

const db = require("./app/models");
db.mongoose
  .connect(db.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to the database!");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Cannot connect to the database!", err);
    process.exit();
  });
```

### index.js

```
  const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const db = {};
db.mongoose = mongoose;
db.url = dbConfig.url;
db.users = require("./user.model.js")(mongoose);
console.log(db.url);
module.exports = db;
```

### user.contoller.js

```
const db = require("../models");
const User = db.users;

// Retrieve all Tutorials from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {

  User.find({ isAdmin: false })
  .then(data => {
    console.log("datanew"+data); // <-- Empty returns here.. []
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message:
        err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving user."
    });
  });
};
```

### user.model.js

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
var schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  password: String,
  email:String,
  isAdmin:Boolean
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

schema.method("toJSON", function() {
  const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
  object.id = _id;
  return object;
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", schema);
return User;
  };
```

### user.route.js

```
module.exports = app => {
const users = require("../controllers/user.controller.js");

var router = require("express").Router();

// Retrieve all Tutorials
router.get("/", users.findAll);

app.use('/api/users', router);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you manually created your MongoDB collection. Users must be in small letters so from the MongoDB interface, change Users => users and you'll be set.

Also your DB connection uri should be:

```
module.exports = {
 url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/TestDb"
 };
```

TestDB is the database while users is the collection. Your uri must point to a db that your code will query collections in.

Your User Model
This is just a slight change but you want to keep your code consistent. User should all be in capitalize form. MongoDB is smart to user plural and small caps automatically in the db.

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
var schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  password: String,
  email:String,
  isAdmin:Boolean
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

schema.method("toJSON", function() {
  const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
  object.id = _id;
  return object;
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", schema);
return User;
  };
```

Comment: I have change like above said.. Server is running but still im getting empty results. PS D:\TestProjects\node-express-mongo\user-portal> node server.js
mongodb://localhost:27017/TestDb
Server is running on port 8080.
Connected to the database!
datanew

Comment: Can you write your query without setting isAdmin so I can figure out what the issue is? For example                     
   User.find({})
  .then(data => {
    console.log("datanew"+data); // <-- Empty returns here.. []
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message:
        err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving user."
    });
  });

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Actually you can  remove
 index.js     
 db.config.js  files 

// *********
add in server.js
const express = require('express')
const mongoose  = require('monggose') 
const app = express()

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/TestDb');
```

Comment: I have tried this but still getting error.